# Matplotlib in Jupyter : Interactive plot (separate window) does not open

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib

I recently switched to new macbook pro(from 2015 to 2017).

From

```
macOS Sierra 10.12.6
conda 4.3.30
Jupyter 4.1.0
Python 2.7.11 | Annaconda custom(x86_64) [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577) on darwin
```

To

```
High Sierra 10.13.2
Jupyter 4.4.0
conda 4.3.30
Python 2.7.14 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Dec  7 2017, 11:07:58) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] on darwin
```

I moved all my data by restoring the new computer with fresh timemachine backup from old computer. Everything works well except `matplotlib`.

In `Jupyter notebook`,

If i run,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
plt.plot(range(10))
plt.show()
```

It works okay with plot showing inline on notebook.

But if I do `%matplotlib`

It goes to `Using matplotlib backend: MacOSX`

but following message is displayed in terminal,

```
[I 13:09:59.765 NotebookApp] Replaying 6 buffered messages
ERROR:tornado.application:Exception in callback <functools.partial object at 0x112208fc8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 605, in _run_callback
    ret = callback()
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 262, in enter_eventloop
    self.eventloop(self)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/eventloops.py", line 278, in loop_cocoa
    show.mainloop()
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'mainloop'
```

And then now, plot does not show up.

```
plt.plot(range(10))
plt.show()
```

This will now result in nothing. The cell executes but nothing happens.

Comment: You may try to edit your matplotlib rc file to set the backend to a different one, e.g. `backend      : TkAgg`.

Comment: i saw this mentioned somewhere but I could not find `matplotlibrc` file

Comment: Before doing anything else, try if a different backend even changes anything. To this end try `%matplotlib tk` instead of `%matplotlib` without any extention.

Comment: hey it worked for simple plot like above but for a 3D plot, it does not display anything. :( the window opens but the figure i blank.

Comment: funny thing is if I use `import matplotlib` and `matplotlib.use('tkAgg'), the plot is plotted in new window but if i close that window, now the cell does not stop executing. I have to force stop the cell through jupyter

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Windows 10 with Python 3.6 and the latest matplotlib package. This has worked for me:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('tkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)
plt.show(block=False)
for i in range(100):
    print(i)
    a = np.random.rand(10,10)
    ax[0].imshow(a)
    a = np.random.rand(10,10)
    ax[1].imshow(a)
    fig.canvas.draw()
```

A call to `matplotlib.use('tkAgg')` has to be before any use of matplot in the code. The key part is `fig.canvas.draw()`

The code above works for me, but when it's a real CPU heavy code, it may take up all power so that the plots are not updated until the loop is over. In this case adding this statement `plt.pause(1e-2)` right after `draw()` helps